# Excel macro to concatenate one row at a time to end of file

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I need an Excel macro to join seven columns of data on each row until the end of the data is reached.  For example if I have a formula like this:

```
=A1&B1&C1&D1&E1&F1&G1
```

How can I write the macro so that it increments for every row to the end of the file in a sequence like this?

```
=A1&B1&C1&D1&E1&F1&G1
=A2&B2&C2&D2&E2&F2&G2
=A3&B3&C3&D3&E3&F3&G3
```

Comment: Would dragging the formula down work for you? (select the range in which you want to copy your formula, in your example H1:H3 and press CTRL+D). Unless you need to do this repeatedly or within a larger macro there is no need for vba.

Comment: I agree with @assylias. Why do you need VBA for this?  Also if you have lot of rows then you might be averse to dragging the formula down. In such a case you can hover the mouse to the bottom right corner of the cell say H1 which has the formula. You will notice that the cursor changes to a "+". Simply double click. I am assuming that you are putting that formula in the 8th Column and your 7th column doesn't have any blank cells in between.

Comment: This works but I had no idea it could be done without VB. This used to be a Macro only thing and I haven't had to use it for several years.  THANKS!  Charles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With so many answers, the main focus on what assylias and I were highlighting has gone to waste :)

However, if you still want a VBA answer. Use this method. This is much **faster** than `Looping` or an `Autofill`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    Set Ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = Ws.Range("A" & Ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> If your range doesn't have a header
    Ws.Range("H1:H" & LastRow).Formula = "=A1&B1&C1&D1&E1&F1&G1"

    '~~> If it does then
    Ws.Range("H2:H" & LastRow).Formula = "=A2&B2&C2&D2&E2&F2&G2"
End Sub
```

If you have 1000's of rows then you might want to switch off `Screenupdating` and change `Calculation` to Manual before you run the code and then reset them at the end of the code.

Comment: This also works perfectly and I prefer it because no matter how big the file is I can just click the macro and resue it.  THANKS!  Charles

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to just fill down as assylias says but if you want to use VBA:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Your Fill Range"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Should copy across the other rows.

Answer (score 0):

I agree 100% with the comments and the other answers, why do you need VBA to do this, but just to answer your original question, this is how I would accomplish it:

```
Sub FillAllWithFormula()
Dim i As Variant
Dim wsht As Worksheet

    'If you are using this for a specific Worksheet use the following
    Set wsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(yourWorksheetName)

    'or if you are always using this for the active sheet use the following
    Set wsht = ActiveSheet

    For i = 1 To wsht.Rows.Count
        'Replace "X" with the column letter you want your formula to appear in
        wsht.Range("X" & i).Formula = "=A" & i & "&B" & i & "&C" & i & "&D" & i & "&E" & i & "&F" & i & "&G" & i
    Next

    Set wsht = Nothing

End Sub
```